# How to put transparent background?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing project in unity and recently put speed indicator in `UI text`, but I also want to put background in `text area`. What do I have to do to put background texture in `text UI`?

Answer (score 2):

Create yourself a panel with a gui image attached to it, then simple attach a gui text also to the gameobject, then you can simply change the panel size and image and it won't affect the text.

Answer (score 1):

Create a UI image GameObject underneath the canvas GameObject. 
Then move the UI text you created so that it's a child of the image GameObject.